# Specific variables calculation

Tags: r

[image]

Hello,I have an issue.I have an excell and I want to calculate and to find Min. =0.000 etc..but I find Min. =1.700 etc. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the `str(C4$grade)`.  Based on your code you are using `& grade` which implies that `grade` is a logical column.  If it is not a logical column, what happens is that is that it will change the column to logical by making the 0 to FALSE and all other values to TRUE in the `filter

Comment: it is a logical column the grade

Comment: So, instead of `summary`, can you do `%>% pull(grade) %>% fivenum`

Comment: Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"

Comment: If it is a logical column, I am not sure how you should get `Max` as 10 and Mean 6.515.  It should be all 1 i.e. .`mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = cyl > 4) %>% pull(cyl) %>% fivenum
[1] 0 0 1 1 1`

Comment: its ok man thanks for helping me.It doesn't work. But I appreciate you help me

Comment: I meant to add to `select(grade) %>%` i.e. `C4 %>% filter(exam == 'S1' & year == 2018 & grade) %>% pull(grade) %>% fivenum`

Comment: Can you please update your post with `dput(head(C4, 20))`

Comment: with that way it shows me the 1.7 6.2 etc I want the up on the image Min 0.0

Comment: ok, then the `filter` step may have removed the `0` values in grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* the problem is your inclusion of `& grade` as a term in your `filter` step.

What's going on is that R wants to interpret each of these terms (`exam=="S1"`, `year==2018`, `grade`) as a *logical* value. When it converts `grade` to logical, 0 becomes `FALSE` and all other values become `TRUE` (try `as.logical(-1:1)` to see an example), so the zero values in your data get removed.

Just delete `& grade` from your code.

Comment: how should it be then?

Comment: I mean I must remove the &grade?

Comment: Yes ... (can you explain why you included it in the first place?)

Comment: it is working :) thank you man